# Problems to send data back to the controller. Parameter is always null MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have problems to send back data from view to controller. I'm quite new to MVC and I can't  figure it out what is the problem.

This is the view:

```
@model IEnumerable<OnlineCarStore.Models.CategoriesVM>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
   @using (Html.BeginForm("SubCategory", "Product"))
   {
        <div class="list-group col-sm-3" style="width:280px;">
            @{var selected = string.Empty;
                if (@HttpContext.Current.Session["selectedCar"] == null)
                {
                    selected = string.Empty;
                }
                else
                {
                    selected = @HttpContext.Current.Session["selectedCar"].ToString();
                }
                foreach (var c in Model)
                {
                    <a href="@Url.Action("SubCategory", "Product", new { selected = selected, id = @c.ID, category = @c.CategoryName })" id="link" class="list-group-item">
                        <span> @c.CategoryName</span>
                    </a>

                    for (int i = 0; i < c.Childrens.Count; i++)
                    {
                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => c.Childrens[i].Item)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => c.Childrens[i].Children)
                    }                       
                }

            }
```

This is the view model for the data that I need:

```
public class CategoriesVM
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int AtpID { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public List<Helpers.TreeItem<Categories>> Childrens { get; set; }
}
```

This is in the controller:

```
public ActionResult SubCategory(IEnumerable<OnlineCarStore.Models.CategoriesVM> Model)
      {
```

. In the Model parameter I need all the data that the CategoriesVM contains, but the Model parameter is always null.
Can you please advise what I'm doing wrong? What I'm missing?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot (and should not) pass all the properties of your Category object via a link click! It works only when your object is lean-flat with very few properties. When your object is complex, this is not ideal!

You should simply pass the unique Id (category id) to the next action method and in which you use this id to query the needed data and use that.

I also noticed that you are setting the same id value to the link in the loop. It will produce multiple anchor tag with same Id value. That is invalid HTML. So let's remove that.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("SubCategory", "Product", new { id = @c.ID })"
                                                               class="list-group-item">
  <span> @c.CategoryName</span>
</a>
```

Now in your `SubCategory` action method

```
public ActionResult SubCategory(int id)
{
  //using the id, get the data needed (may be the category & subcategories)
  // to do : Return something
}
```